# Create a table and take data from json file in react js

Tags: reactjs, json, crud

I have the following fields in react js from which I should be able to perform crud operation with json file but have no idea how the Json file is created. Only I know is how to make UI. So, it would be very grateful if some would teach me how to do that. My code up to now:
App.js

```
import React from 'react'

 const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Create Table</h3>
      <hr />
      <form className='form'>
        <label className= "layout">Layout:</label>
        <input
          type= "text"
          placeholder="select layout"
         
        />
        <label className="name"> Name:</label>
        <input 
          placeholder="Input Name" 
        />
        <label className = "capacity">Capacity:</label>
        <input 
          type= "text"
          placeholder="Enter Number Of Capacity"
        />
        <label className= "status">Status:</label>
        <input className= "input"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        <label className="Image">Image:</label>
        <button className = "bttn">Choose File</button>
        <p className = "para">No file choosen</p>
        <button className= "btn">Create Table</button>
        <button className= "button">Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

All I want to know is how to create the fake data for all layouts, names, capacity and images to be able to choose and be able to display it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of crud in Jsonplaceholder: https://codesandbox.io/s/ey0w4?file=/src/index.js

I hope it's useful, if you faced any problem, let me know